# Error building libtensorflow_inference.so

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow from source following these [steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#next) 
on a MacOS environment. The configuration and the build with bazel was successful but when I try to generate the **libtensorflow_inference.so** to add the native support for my android app following this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/README.md) 
 I get an error while executing the bazel build command in the provided link. Here is the error :

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_aboussaada/60096eee641a597e34b524b059acf8b3/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:265:1: Executing genrule @protobuf_archive//:generate_js_well_known_types_embed failed (Exit 126): bash failed: error executing command 
  (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_aboussaada/60096eee641a597e34b524b059acf8b3/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7 \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \
  /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive/js_embed external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types/any.js external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types/struct.js external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types/timestamp.js > bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types_embed.cc')
/bin/bash: bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive/js_embed: cannot execute binary file
Target //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 0,361s, Critical Path: 0,08s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

i changed my NDK version to r12b since I was using r14b following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541845/when-i-use-bazel-to-bulid-libtensorflow-inference-so) and rebuild tensorflow but nothing works. 
I'm working with python 2.7 and the latest version of tensorflow.
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

i cloned the project this time using `--recurse-submodules` to prevent protobuf compilation errors as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) and I got a new error :

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_aboussaada/60096eee641a597e34b524b059acf8b3/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:265:1: Executing genrule @protobuf_archive//:generate_js_well_known_types_embed failed (Exit 126): bash failed: error executing command 
  (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_aboussaada/60096eee641a597e34b524b059acf8b3/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki \
  /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive/js_embed external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types/any.js external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types/struct.js external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types/timestamp.js > bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types_embed.cc')
/bin/bash: bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/protobuf_archive/js_embed: cannot execute binary file
Target //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 0,517s, Critical Path: 0,12s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Looks like your installation of the javascript protocol buffer compiler is broken. How did you install it? You might need to use ndk 14b

Comment: i was using ndk 14b but I had the same error. and about the js protocol buffer compiler, I didn't do nothing manually I just installed tensorflow following their website.. is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: i cloned the project with this `--recurse-submodules` to prevent protobuf compilation problems as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android)  and i got a new error ! please check my updated question